# CGAL Scale-Space reconstruction with normals and colors

Tags: tuples, cgal, point-clouds, 3d-reconstruction

I am using CGAL for point cloud processing, and generating mesh out of it using Scale-Space reconstruction.

I recently require to save color and normal information. So, I used `boost::tuple(Point_3, Vector_3, CGAL::Color)` for filters: simplification, outlier removal and normal estimations/orientation. Now triangulating the cloud using Scale-Space reconstruction is only accepting vector of points, not the tuple I have created.

```
typedef CGAL::Scale_space_surface_reconstruction_3< Kernel > Reconstruction;
Reconstruction reconstruct;
reconstruct.insert( points.begin(), points.end());
//Error if points is defined as vector<PointNormalColorTuple>
//Works if points are vector<Point_3>
//There is no parameter in insert and reconstruct_surface, where I can define property map:
//CGAL::Nth_of_tuple_property_map<0,PointNormalColorTuple>()
```

I cannot copy data in a new `vector<Point_3>` as color information will be lost.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: It is indeed not possible. I suggest you submit a [feature request](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues).

Comment: Thanks @sloriot for the clarification.

Comment: Actually I think that the order of the points is preserved. That is the indices in the reconstruction should be the one of your input points.

Comment: That's correct. I can obtain points from input cloud using indices in the reconstruction, but reconstruction need to be done only on vector points.

Comment: Use a [`transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html).